# How to get rid of the built-in Paste shortcut in TRichEdit?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-11-alexandria, trichedit

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I have a `TRichEdit` control. (Please note that the `TRichEdit` class in Delphi 11 Alexandria differs from previous Delphi versions).

Now, it seems that `TRichEdit` has a BUILT-IN Paste command and Shortcut: When I press CTRL+V, then the clipboard content gets inserted (image, formatted text).

So far, so good. But to allow the user to paste PLAIN TEXT (i.e., unformatted text) explicitly - even if there is formatted text on the clipboard, I have created a "Paste Plain Text" menu item command:

```
procedure TForm1.menuitemPastePlainTextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var ClipboardPlainText := Vcl.Clipbrd.Clipboard.AsText;
  RichEdit1.SelText := ClipboardPlainText;
end;
```

I have assigned the shortcut SHIFT+CTRL+V to this command. (This shortcut is widely used among many applications for pasting unformatted text). However, when I type SHIFT+CTRL+V in RichEdit1, the FORMATTED text from the clipboard is pasted! Obviously, a BUILT-IN SHIFT+CTRL+V command in RichEdit1 has a higher priority than my custom shortcut.

So, how can I get rid of the built-in SHIFT+CTRL+V command in RichEdit1 to paste Plain Text?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue in Delphi 10.4, so it seems like this is a new issue in the new `TRichEdit` of Delphi 11. I think I consider this to be a bug.

Comment: "Obviously, a BUILT-IN SHIFT+CTRL+V command in RichEdit1 has a higher priority than my custom shortcut." Are you sure? What does this command do? My guess would be that the Rich Edit control says "Ah, Ctrl+V is pressed!" when you press Shift+Ctrl+V.

Comment: That's my guess too.

Comment: Well, I'll have a look at this the next time I have access to a Delphi 11 installation.

Comment: After further tests, for reasons unknown to me, the shortcut SHIFT+CTRL+V now takes precedence over the built-in shortcut: Now, when I press SHIFT+CTRL+V, the `menuitemPastePlainTextClick` handler gets executed, and the Plain Text is inserted - even if there is formatted text on the clipboard.

Comment: That's the behaviour I'd expect.